# Adding literal_column to Flask-SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add some scalar value column to the selection that uses Flask-SQLAlchemy pagination functionality. Currently i have:

```
records = Item.query.paginate(1, 3, False).items
```

How do i have to edit this code to add column that contains total number of pages (and ideally one more column with total records number)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try passing passing a dictionary to json.dumps:

```
paginated = Item.query.paginate(1, 3, False)
results = {
    "records": paginated.items,
    "num_pages": paginated.pages,
    "total_count": paginated.total   
}

return json.dumps(results, cls=AlchemyEncoder)
```

Answer (score 0):

`paginate` returns a `Pagination` object which contains attributes like `pages`, and `total`. [See the API.](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/api/#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.Pagination)

```
paginated = Item.query.paginate(1, 3, False)
num_pages = paginated.pages # gives you total number of pages
total_count = paginated.total
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but the main question is "How to add [literal_column()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column) (with the value of num_pages and/or total_count) to the resulting QuerySet?"

Comment: Why do you need this as a separate column? The `paginate` function already returns the number of pages in the query set.

Comment: My code returns (`return json.dumps(records, cls=AlchemyEncoder)`) json representation of a paginate().items query set, and i want num_pages&total_count to be a part of this json data, so that i could return all info (db rows + a couple of summary values) within a single http response.